# אדנים - Singular vs. Plural

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, parashat-vayeishev, book-of-malachi

I don't know if this is more Hebrew or if it is about biblical explication.

In [Malachi 1:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.1.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the text reads וְאִם־אֲדוֹנִ֣ים אָנִי֩ which is translated (on Sefaria and Chabad) as "If I am a master" turning adonim (which I would have thought was plural) into a singular.

The [Metzudat Tziyon](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.1.6?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_Zion_on_Malachi.1.6.1&lang2=bi) writes, "דרך המקרא להזכיר שם אדנות בלשון רבים וכן אדוני יוסף (בראשית ל״ט" That (my loose translation) it is the way of the biblical text to invoke the concept of master-ship in the plural, as in Bereishit 39 -- adonei yosef, the masterS of Yosef.

And [Bereishit 39:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.39.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it does read וַיִּקַּח֩ אֲדֹנֵ֨י יוֹסֵ֜ף.

This leads to two questions --

1. Why isn't this pluralization followed in any of the other uses of a-d-n in perek 39 (which casts doubt on the M"Tz's insight and leaves me wondering about why the plural was used in Malachi) and
2. How could 39:20 be constructed in biblical Hebrew to reflect a singular master in that pasuk? If pluralizing it is the only way, then it isn't significant, but required.

EDIT (3 yrs later)

[Tehillim 136:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.136.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) describes God as "Adonei ha'adonim" the lordS of lords. Why not make it "Adon ha'adonim"? Why is the first descriptor a plural?

Comment: Note Elohim is also plural

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, and IIRC the Ramban explains that as the master of all forces with the pluralization not on the master, but on the other forces which are mastered.

Comment: Ibn ezra explains elohim as the royal we; plural for respect.